# Update Mysql based on time work but function in different day?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this when I update with my SQL I had two changes in different day, I want change just in current day look what happen in the table

```
-------------------------------------------------------
  service    loket     number    status    get_ticket
-------------------------------------------------------
      1        null      6         4       2017/3/12 12:00:07
      1        null      5         4       2017/3/12 11:34:09
      1        null      4         4       2017/3/12 11:02:20
      1        null      3         4       2017/3/12 10:42:10
      1        null      2         4       2017/3/12 09:32:10
      1          1       1         8       2017/3/12 09:32:10   <----when i updated my current date
      1        null      6         4       2017/2/28 12:05:07
      1        null      5         4       2017/2/28 11:37:09
      1        null      4         4       2017/2/28 10:02:20
      1        null      3         4       2017/2/28 09:42:10
      1        null      2         4       2017/2/28 09:36:10
      1          1       1         8       2017/32/28 08:32:10  <----this changed too but i want it not change because this column in different day
```

Query:

```
update tqueue 
set status = 8, loket = 1 
where service = 1 
  and number = (SELECT number 
                FROM (SELECT * FROM tqueue) AS something
                WHERE STATUS =  '4' AND get_ticket >= CURDATE() 
                  AND get_ticket < DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
                GROUP BY service);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using a subquery?

```
update tqueue
    set status = 8,
        loket = 1
    where service = 1 and status =  4 and
          get_ticket >= curdate( )  and
          get_ticket < date_add( curdate( ) , interval 1 day)
    limit 1;
```

Comment: hey it work, i dont think is so simple like that, i'm use subquery because error using query thanks gordon it worked...